# How do I save scraped items to multiple .jl files?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I want to run a scraper that saves different types of items to separate JSON Lines files.

My `settings.py` has this:

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
   'permits.pipelines.PermitTypePipeline': 300,
   'permits.pipelines.PermitNumberPipeline': 301,
}
```

My `pipelines.py` has this:

```
class PermitTypePipeline(object):
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        return item

class PermitNumberPipeline(object):
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        return item
```

`items.py` has this:

```
class PermitType(scrapy.Item):
    permitWebCode=  scrapy.Field()

class PermitNumber(scrapy.Item):
    permitNumber=   scrapy.Field()
```

`my_spider.py` has this:

```
def parse(self,response):
  ## Some scraper code here ... 
  yield PermitType(permitWebCode=someScrapedVariable)
  yield PermitNumber(permitNumber=anotherScrapedVariable)
```

How do I save the yielded `PermitType` object to `permit_types.jl` and the `PermitNumber` object to `permit_number.jl`?

Answer (score 1):

A rather blunt but fonctionnal approach would be to create a pipeline that recognizes the type of the yielded item and then store it in the corresponding json file. It would probably look like this:

```
import json
import ClassA
import ClassB

class JsonWriterPipeline(object):

def close_spider(self, spider):
    self.file.close()

def process_item(self, item, spider):
    if type(item) is ClassA:
        self.file = open('classA.jl', 'w')
    elif type(item) is ClassB:
        self.file = open('classB.jl', 'w')
    else:
        return item
    line = json.dumps(dict(item)) + "\n"
    self.file.write(line)
    return item
```

Tell me if this worked as I did not try it myself.